# Inlet filter on washing machine clogging

Tags: washing-machine, filter

I have a whirlpool front loading washing machine.

Model WFW9150ww00

Each inlet valve has an inserted filter with a very fine mesh.  The first couple of years were fine.  In the last 6 months I have twice had to take off the hose, extract the filter with a pair of pliers, and blow it free of invisible crud.  That is, I couldn't see anything blocking the holes.

The snit mode it gets into works like this:

It will abort a cycle and beep.  Decoding the beeps gives me a message like "Inadequate fill rate"  Looking for answers to this gave me the clean the filter tip.

On several occasions I have unplugged it, plugged it in, and was able to restart the cycle.  Sometimes this works.  Sometimes not.

Compounding this:  We have our own well.  Our water pressure fluctuates between 55 and 75 psi.  My current hypothesis:  When the power cycle fixes it, it occurred when the pressure was low, making the flow rate worse.  Cycling it allowed the well pump to kick in and at the higher pressure it was fine.

I don't think it is just the water.  We use the same well for irrigation and the water passes through a 200 mesh disc filter (different line).  That filter needs to cleaned about every 2 million liters.

so...

1. Can I replace the screen with a coarser mesh?  Internally what exactly  is dependent on such a fine mesh screen?
2. How does the flow sensor work? Can it be marginal?

Comment: Might try an acid soak (vinegar or citric) when cleaning the filter - might also prefilter the water to this appliance (or the whole house.) Ahh, for the days when alt.architechture.alternative was a happening place - Hi Sherwood. ;^)

Comment: I've done a soak in CLR.  This makes no visible difference.  But it works.  Can taking a thousandth of an inch of 50% rust coverage make that much difference?

Comment: Have you checked your well booster lately? Could be that the pressure in it is too low. Do you notice lower pressure in other fixtures? Take longer to fill dishwasher if you have one? Lower at faucets etc. A pre-filter on the line to the washer could help, but it could also reduce the pressure further if it clogs. More surface to clog, but if your water is that bad....a filter would help. I think it's more related to a booster or pump issue and not the washer inlet mesh filter.

Comment: Good idea.  Submerged pump.  No booster.  Gauge on the pressure tank and the morning shower both agree that pressure is normal.